# redirect_to redirects the same page, test doesn't fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I need to redirect_to users/index page when submitting form but browser shows the same page, erases all the forms and shows this strange address:

```
http://localhost:3000/signup?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=aKZ7qWC9ZUMyFXYNxvVfL%2F4BpTSB0sZtpm1a4AWNvWE%3D&user%5Bsecondname%5D=&user%5Bfirstname%5D=&user%5Bpatronymic%5D=&user%5Bdateofbirth%283i%29%5D=&user%5Bdateofbirth%282i%29%5D=&user%5Bdateofbirth%281i%29%5D=&user%5Blogin%5D=&user%5Bemail%5D=&user%5Bpassword%5D=&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=&commit=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F
```

Same thing happens when I submit it with empty forms (no error listing)
Though RSpec says that all tests pass...

My USERS_CONTROLLER.RB:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    redirect_to action: :index
  end
end
```

My USERS/NEW.HTML.ERB

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %> <h1>Регистрация</h1>

<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin form-horizontal">

        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :secondname, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Фамилия" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :firstname, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Имя" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :patronymic, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Отчество" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%= f.label :dateofbirth, :"Дата рождения", :class => "control-label" %>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.date_select :dateofbirth, start_year: 1933, end_year: 2006, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'День', :month => 'Месяц', :year => 'Год' } %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :login, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Логин" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Email" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Пароль" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Подтверждение пароля" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.submit "Зарегистрироваться", :id => "register", :class => "btn btn-info" %>
                </div>
            </div>

        <% end %>
    </form> </div>
```

My _ERROR_MESSAGES.HTML.ERB:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

PART OF USER_PAGES_SPEC.RB

```
describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "register" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "user_firstname",              with: "Ivan"
    fill_in "user_secondname",             with: "Ivanov"
    fill_in "user[patronymic]",            with: "Ivanovich"
    select "2000",                         from: "user[dateofbirth(1i)]"
    select "November",                     from: "user[dateofbirth(2i)]"
    select "11",                           from: "user[dateofbirth(3i)]"
    fill_in "user[login]",                 with: "IvanIvanov"
    fill_in "user[email]",                 with: "Ivan@gmail.com"
    fill_in "user[password]",              with: "foobar"
    fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", with: "foobar"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Wow! It turned out that problem is in tag `<form>`. Without it all workes fine, but why? Bootstrap says: Add .form-horizontal to the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the two tags of the `<form>` that you used. Also it is advisable to render the error messages outside or before the `form_for` tag. For adding class or any html attribute can be added to `form_for` or similar tags like this `:attr_name => "value"` so if you want to add `class` to suppose `myclass` you can do it like `:class => "myclass"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `redirect_to` is wrong, it should redirect to a path (url).

Try:

```
redirect_to users_path
```

Comment: I replaced it, now address doesn't change but page is still the same =(

Comment: It worked before I added some css, bootstrap and changed names to Russian. Don't know how it can ifluence this. Looks like I changed something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly redirect to an action also just use

```
redirect_to :action => :index
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fix that. I don't understand why error messages age disappeared and test is ok.

Comment: Error messages that I needed, like this:
The form contains 4 errors.
* Login can't be blank
* Login is too short (minimum is 5 characters)
* Password can't be blank
* Password confirmation can't be blank

They were gone not after your help of course, before.

Now it is all ok, it was wrong because I didn't know that form helper form_for creates tag form in html (my first steps in ruby heh ^__^) and added it in users/new.html.erb. But anyway I don't understand how to add class form-horizontal in it not with <form> but with form_for.
Anyway thank you for your attention!!!

Comment: so how can I help you now?  is something still wrong or working fine?  and you used my method or not?

Comment: Yes, both methods work good, thank you.
It is working fine.
If you can help me with how to add class to form_for it will be wonderfull!

Comment: @WiseDash yeah class or any html attribute can be added to `form_for` or similar tags like this `:attr_name => "value"` so if you want to add `class` to suppose `myclass` you can do it like `:class => "myclass"`

Comment: @WiseDash Please accept the answer if it helped you. It will help me as well as others.

Comment: Yes it helped thanx. First I added it so: <%= form_for(@user), 
:class => form_horizontal do |f| %>
But it didn't work.
So I found that it should look like: 
<%= form_for(@user, :class => "form-horizontal") do |f| %>
(Didn't know that it must be in brackets with user, maybe it will help somebody who is as newbie as me)

Comment: Sure I can accept your answer because it really helped me but with the second question. Maybe it will be better to write a new answer that says that problem was in two tags <form>? How do you think? It is my first Stack-question at all))

Comment: @WiseDash I added a new answer.